# htaccess mask upload directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Howcome this is not working?

It is supposed to mask the /uploads/ directory on the server.

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^artwork"
RewriteRule ^\/artwork\/\w+\/(.{32})-(\d+)&(\d+).jpg|gif|jpeg uploads/covers/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/artwork"
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

URL : `example.com/test` should go to `public/index.php?url=test` (this works fine)

URL : `example.com/artwork/avatar/qmsdkfj-40&40.jpg` should go to = `/uploads/qmsdkfj.jpg`

It works fine if I remove the second RewriteRule, but when I add it again it still redirects to public/index.php.
Notice that the second rewriterule sends all to public/ folder.
I think maybe [L] is not forcing it to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fault.
After redirecting ^artwork it was still redirecting ^uploads

So this is the new working code

```
RewriteRule ^\/?artwork\/\w+\/(.{32})-(\d+)&(\d+).jpg|gif|jpeg uploads/covers/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!artwork|uploads)(.*) public/$1
```

Hope this helps somone else.